# If or statement with $1 parameters keeps failing

Tags: bash-scripting

I have written the following bash script to run bleachbit.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Use p for preview and c for activating cleaners after script name   
followed by a gap. Example: bb p or bb c.

if  [[ $1 != "p" ]] || [[ $1 != "c" ]] || [[ $# -eq 0 ]]
then    echo 'No, or false parameter selected! Please use p for "preview"     
              or c for "clean"!'
else

# /usr/bin/bleachbit -$1 adobe_reader.cache
/usr/bin/bleachbit -$1 adobe_reader.mru
/usr/bin/bleachbit -$1 adobe_reader.tmp
.
.
.
fi
```

The script is called bb. I always get the same message whether I just run bb, bb x, bb g, bb c or bb p.

```
 No, or false parameter selected! Please use p for "preview"     
          or c for "clean"!
```

The actual bleachbit commands never execute. I am a bit of a newbie so I appreciate any help I can get on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main check is logically impossible to satisfy:

```
[[ $1 != "p" ]] || [[ $1 != "c" ]]
```

Because you have "(not p) OR (not c)", this will return TRUE when $1 is "c" (because it is not "p") and likewise it will return TRUE when $1 is "p" (because it is not "c"), and so you get the error message in both cases.

The only way it would return FALSE is if the variable held both values *simultaneously*, but Bash does not have quantum superpositions just yet. (Perl might.)

This would work with a `&&` (AND) operator instead:

```
if [[ $1 != "p" ]] && [[ $1 != "c" ]]; then
```

```
if [[ $1 != "p" && $1 != "c" ]]; then
```

For clarity you could use `!` (NOT) to flip the condition around:

```
if ! [[ $1 == "p" || $1 == "c" ]]; then
```

(The parameter count check $# is redundant here, so I removed it.)

To simplify it further, right-hand side of `[[` supports wildcards:

```
if [[ $1 != [pc] ]]; then
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply grawity. It has fixed the problem.